# iptables for modifying tcpmss value

Tags: iptables

I have a VPN router, and i need to lower TCP MSS value for traffic going through. I am confused about which iptables table is needed to do the job.

I lean towards the mangle/forward combination -

```
  iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -o GRE_+ -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1361
```

But i see other people implementing it in default filter table - and seems it works also (atleast with OUTPUT option)

Could you explain to me why changing TCP MSS works in both tables and what is the more correct way ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's take a look at the [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg):

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

You can see there are the *mangle/OUTPUT* and the *filter/OUTPUT* chains, and along the path a *reroute check*. The *mangle/OUTPUT* chain (as well as conntrack's NAT) has a special property, that doesn't have the *filter/OUTPUT* chain: it will [trigger a reroute check](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_mangle.c?h=linux-5.4.y#n80) [whenever interesting parts of a packet have been changed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_mangle.c?h=linux-5.4.y#n56) (to be honest, I'm surprised to not see *filter/OUTPUT* *after* reroute check in the schematic, because the reroute check might simply be the *netfilter*'s `ip_route_me_harder()` function).

The [TCPMSS target](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#TCPMSS) is merely altering the TCP MSS option, which is not part of the "interesting parts" checked in the *mangle/OUTPUT* chain (IP addresses, TOS, firewall mark) and will thus never trigger a reroute check. So this target, if not used in synergy with some other rules and/or priorities requiring it to be placed in one place or the other for unrelated reasons, has exactly the same behaviour when used in *filter/OUTPUT* or *mangle/OUTPUT*.

That said, in the routing/forwarding case, the distinction between the *mangle/FORWARD* chain and the *filter/FORWARD* chain is completely arbitrary: there is no functional difference between them, except that *mangle/FORWARD* is traversed before *filter/FORWARD* (it has a lower priority/precedence) and that some targets might arbitrarily be allowed only in one or the other rather than both. Except for this priority, contrary to the OUTPUT case, there's no compelling technical reason to have both existing. If the route had to be altered by mangling, this should have already be done in *mangle/PREROUTING* this time, before the route decision even happens.

In *iptables*, the *filter* table is traditionally used for ACCEPT/DROP kind of decisions, while the *mangle* table is traditionally used for altering packets. So using TCPMSS in the *mangle* table would seem more logical, but you don't have to follow this, especially if it's the single rule that would end up in *mangle/FORWARD*.

By contrast, in *nftables* (where you create your own custom *tables*: they aren't fixed), the specic *route-altering* behaviour of iptables' *mangle/OUTPUT* chain has been separated and put in its [specific *type route*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes#Chains), existing only for output: a `type route hook output` chain. So whatever the mangling action you're doing, you can choose if it is allowed to trigger a reroute check by placing it in this kind of chain instead of the `type filter hook output` chain. Every other case (including routing/forwarding) would use the *filter* type, as there's no *mangle* type anymore. In *nftables* for the OUTPUT case, it would seem more logical to put this [alteration](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Mangle_TCP_options) in a `type filter hook output` chain rather than a `type route hook output` chain (I'm not naming the table, you could add both types of chains in the same table, that's not equivalent to *iptables*).

Comment: thanks for so deep answer. I will use filter table. Also i've noticed if i open a new table (for example mangle) the server uses more CPU resources. I think it's wise to use as low as possible different tables.